# Assigning a capability to a user role (code check)

Tags: user-roles

I wrote this piece of code to add manage_options capability to my shop_managers, and it does work. I wanted to ask before i move this code to my live site, if the function is called in the right place.
I thank you in advance!

```
add_action('init', 'activate_cap_shopmanagers');
function activate_cap_shopmanagers() {
        // get the shop manager role's object from WP_Role class
        $shopmanager = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
 
        // add the capability
        $shopmanager->add_cap( 'manage_options' );
    }
```

### Edit

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_activation' );
function my_plugin_activation() {
  add_option( 'my_plugin_activation','just-activated' );
  $shopmanager = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
  $shopmanager->add_cap( 'manage_options' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init','my_plugin_initialize' );
function my_plugin_initialize() {
    if( is_shop_manager() && get_option( 'my_plugin_activation' ) == 'just-activated' ) {
    delete_option( 'my_plugin_activation' );
    }
}
```

is_shop_manager() is a function i have in my functions.php

```
function is_shop_manager() {
    global $current_user;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( isset( $user->roles[0] ) && $user->roles[0] == 'shop_manager' ) {
        return true;    // when user is shop manager
    } else {
        return false;   // when user is not shop manager
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the `init` hook means that the cap is set on *every page load*.
A better approach is to write a small plugin and set the cap *once* by using the [plugin activation hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/). And remove it using the deactivation hook.

Comment: I made an edit. Would that be close to what you suggested?
I am not very familiar with the plugin activation hooks. I thank you in advance!

Comment: If the activation function is working, then it should be okay.  The `admin_init` function serves no real purpose.